# How to connect mysql user to a server AWS EC2?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm using AWS and I just installed MySQL on EC2 environment with ubuntu 14, I created my root with which I can connect via SSH normally, but I created another user with privileges grant all so that someone else can upload changes to a DB and I tried to connect through a standard mode with the public dns of my EC2 but I refused. I'm doing wrong ?, I need to fix something? ... I opened port 3306 respective in my security group assigned to my EC2. I hope you can help me

Comment: On you security group, is it allowed to access from 0.0.0.0/0 or a IP range? Is your instance inside a VPC? How is the VPCs security group?

Comment: mysql/aurora port 3306 anywhere 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: What commands did you try to connect?

Comment: I created another user and want to connect from workbeach without using ssh or key.pem

Comment: And your database is local on that EC2? Or is it on a RDS?

Comment: is local on EC2 with ubutu, please some solution?

Comment: If your DB is Local you will have to use a SSH user to ssh into the Ubuntu first and then connect to the MYSQL running locally. So the that DB user you created should be a linux user too and not just a MYSQL user. You cannot do that without SSH but you can do that without key by creating a SFTP user who can log in to the server by using password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check for few things,

- The user you created should have host ip through which you are connecting. At the time of creating user and granting you must ahve supplied an ip.
- Look for the bind-dns entry in my.cnf and comment it with #.
- Restart mysql server. It should work for you now.